# How to extract text using regex for various text types

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
a = "Office: (000) 987-9728, Mobile: (000) 312-9725"
b = "Mobile: (000) 312-8750, Office: (000) 987-9728"
c = "Mobile: (000) 312-8750"
d = "Office: (000) 987-9728"
search_office_phone = re.search("Office:\s?(.*),|Office:\s?(.*)",a)
if search_office_phone:
    office_number = search_office_phone.group(1)
    print(office_number)
```

Here is a sample of the desired solution: `(000) 987-9728, (000) 312-9725`

These are the various text that can be formed, but using regex I need to get the solution above.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: when I check with d it gets none

Comment: why `(000) 312-9725` should be captured?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That re.search is not correct I need a regex expression where AT LAST IT CAN HAVE COMMA OR NOT

Comment: The question is really not well written. I think the regular expression you provide is also incorrect, at least according with your expected output

Comment: You are printing *office_number* but your required output includes a mobile number. Maybe you should explain **exactly** what you're hoping to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[re.sub(r"Office: |Mobile: ", "", s) for s in [a, b, c, d]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

a = "Office: (000) 987-9728, Mobile: (000) 312-9725"
b = "Mobile: (000) 312-8750, Office: (000) 987-9728"
c = "Mobile: (000) 312-8750"
d = "Office: (000) 987-9728"

pattern = r"Office:\s*\((.*?)\)(?:,|$)"
search_office_phone = re.search(pattern, a)

if search_office_phone:
    office_number = search_office_phone.group(0)
    print("Required solution:", office_number)
```

Comment: Solution is getting wrong  your solution: (000) 987-9728, Mobile: (000)

Comment: updated check out

Comment: Actually this solution is not proper solution. Your are checking by count of numbers. but I am checking whether the text can have "comma" or not in between

Comment: updated the code checkout

Comment: why can I use (.*).. but "comma" is coming with your solution .. I dont want count of numbers

Comment: updated the code checkout

Comment: solution is empty

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're just trying to extract phone numbers that conform to a specific pattern - i.e., (nnn) nnn-nnnn

If that's the case then:

```
import re

a = "Office: (000) 987-9728, Mobile: (000) 312-9725"
b = "Mobile: (000) 312-8750, Office: (000) 987-9728"
c = "Mobile: (000) 312-8750"
d = "Office: (000) 987-9728"

pattern = re.compile(r'\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}')

for s in a, b, c, d:
    print(', '.join(pattern.findall(s)))
```

**Output:**

```
(000) 987-9728, (000) 312-9725
(000) 312-8750, (000) 987-9728
(000) 312-8750
(000) 987-9728
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import re, as you did.

> re.compile((?<="Office:)|(?<="Mobile)| (\d\d\d)\s\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d)

tried to make the regex simple since You mentioned you were a beginner as well.  let me know if this pattern works for you! thank